# Match corresponding peaks/valleys of similar histograms in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I'm currently working on a project where I have to compare similar histograms of image intensity. These histograms are obtained from photos taken under different illumination conditions.

I know that OpenCV offers the *compareHist* function. However this function returns a metric of similarity and I'm looking for a method that matches corresponding peaks/valleys between similar histograms.

For instance, if we have two photos of the same subject, one underexposed and one with the "ideal" exposure, their histograms of intensity might look something like the image in the following URL:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLIGR.png

As shown by the arrows, the peaks in one histogram also exist in the other. Anyone has a suggestion on how to match corresponding peaks?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implementation of DTW (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) to compare the histograms.

Using dynamic programming, you can create a matrix that calculates DTW.  Then, you can trace back through the matrix to find the relations between different parts of the histograms.

After that, it's simply a matter of extracting only the peaks.